# VS code move rows upward on autosave

Tags: visual-studio-code

When my autosave mode is enabled and I write something no matter where in the code. when it saves it. The code moves few lines upward.. In the begining was one line and after few days it started with around 5 to 10...

When I click Ctrl + Z to remove what ever I wrote I need to click it 3 or 4 times.

[Before I write something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5TMS.png)

[After I write what ever and it autosave it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjru5.png)

This is my settings.json file.

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.requireConfig": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "yaml.schemas": {
    "file:///home/sm/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-3.0.1/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
  },
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
  "[php]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.lineHeight": 2,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "twig": "html"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": null,
  "eslint.options": {},
  "files.associations": {
    "*.twig": "twig"
  },
  "[twig]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "mblode.twig-language-2"
  },
  "php.format.rules.spaceBeforeColonInReturnType": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro Darker",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",


}
```

[All the extentsions that I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BuSc.png)

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Tried to stop extentions
On/Off on autosave mode
Reload window
Restart the system

Comment: what happens if you disable the prettier extension and reload or reload with extensions disabled and try again? "_Tried to stop extentions_" and what did you find? Possibly related: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/409 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71707

Comment: When I stopeed the extention today the problem dissapear, but yesterday it didnt.. I did update on the extentions today and when I stopped prettier the problem dissapear. I need prettier. Its part of the requirement. 
What to do ?

Comment: After 2 hours when it was stopped vs code start having the same problem... It not from prettier...